# How do display JSON in Django template? Block.io API

Tags: json, django

I am testing the api from block.io https://block.io/api/simple/python

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "network" : "BTCTEST",
    "available_balance" : "0.0",
    "pending_received_balance" : "0.0",
    "balances" : [
      {
        "user_id" : 0,
        "label" : "default",
        "address" : "2NCjjB8iVKu9jnYpNcYKxxRYP9w6eWXZAq4",
        "available_balance" : "0.00000000",
        "pending_received_balance" : "0.00000000"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to display for example only the wallet address of the user in question so that he can make a deposit.

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from block_io import BlockIo
version = 2 # API version
block_io = BlockIo('28a8-ba34-8b81-137d', '1111111', version)

def index(request):
    balance = block_io.get_address_balance(labels='shibe1')
    context = {'balance': balance}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

home.html

```
<h1>Block.io API</h1>
{{ balance }}

<h1>I want display example this data</h1>
<h1>Label: default</h1>
<h1>Available balance: 0.00000000</h1>
<h1>Pending received balance: 0.00000000</h1>
<h1>Address: 2NCjjB8iVKu9jnYpNcYKxxRYP9w6eWXZAq4</h1>
```

When I do this all the data is displayed but example I only want to address

[Image displayed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Nt2.png)

```
{'status': 'success', 'data': {'network': 'BTCTEST', 'available_balance': '0.0', 'pending_received_balance': '0.0', 'balances': [{'user_id': 1, 'label': 'shibe1', 'address': '2NADUMWksxJZRKPSNXya8R2LYQY2fGa5mNY', 'available_balance': '0.00000000', 'pending_received_balance': '0.00000000'}]}}
```

How can I refer only to the data that I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform all sorts of [lookups on variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#variables) in Django Template language using just the `.` operator. Also your data has a list so you would need to loop over it:

```
<h1>Block.io API</h1>
<h1>I want display example this data</h1>
{% for bal in balance.data.balances %}
    <h1>Label: {{ bal.label }}</h1>
    <h1>Available balance: {{ bal.available_balance }}</h1>
    <h1>Pending received balance: {{ bal.pending_received_balance }}</h1>
    <h1>Address: {{ bal.address }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below file changes :

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from block_io import BlockIo
version = 2 # API version
block_io = BlockIo('28a8-ba34-8b81-137d', '1111111', version)

def index(request):
    balance = block_io.get_address_balance(labels='shibe1')
    context = {'all_balance': balance['data']['balances']}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

home.html

```
<h1>Block.io API</h1> 

{% for balance in all_balance %}
    <h1>Label: {{ balance.label }}</h1>
    <h1>Available balance: {{ balance.available_balance }}</h1>
    <h1>Pending received balance: {{ balance.pending_received_balance }}</h1>
    <h1>Address: {{ balance.address }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```